# Resetting the preview after taking a photo - Android Camera.startpreview() fails

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to build an app which takes photos and processes them later on.
So far I've been able to access the camera, deliver the preview, and take a photo. However after I do take a photo I can't resume my preview to take more photos. It just locks and if I try to use Camera.stopPreview and then Camera.startPreview to "restart" my preview I get 
the following error:

05-05 21:19:24.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
05-05 21:19:24.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)

I need to reset it to take multiple photos. 
If i comment out and don't mess with the preview (single photo take) the app works.

After extensive hours of research I can't find a solution.

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/dJELpsWN

[LATER EDIT]

Minutes after asking the question I found the problem was that I was calling Camera.startPreview too fast while it didn't have time to save/process the photo.